# Find combination of bank notes for particular sum

Tags: algorithm

How to issue money efficiently. For example if you have 1 bank note of 100$, 1 bank note of 50$ and 2 bank notes of 30$. How to determine that we need 50$ and two of 30$ to achieve 110$ summary.

In other words, we have fixed number of bank note types: 30$ (two bank notes), 50$ (one bank note), 100$ (one bank note). The problem is to determine which bank notes we should take to get a particular sum, for example, 110$? In this case we should take two 30$ bank notes and one 50$ bank note.

We can't use greedy algorithm here because if we take 100$ bank note first, then we can't achieve 110$ summary.

Which data structure do we need to use for storing bank notes? Simply quantity of each bank note type or may be an array to store each bank note: [100, 50, 30, 30]

And what is the algorithm to find which bank notes do we need to get a particular sum?

Comment: There are a bunch of related questions, although those usually use coins. I can't find an exact duplicate right now. Have you tried [searching](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=algorithm+coins+combination)?

Comment: Generalized, this is the Subset Sum problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).  Standard solution is O(2^(n/2)).  there is also a possible pseudo-polynomial solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic programming approach. You keep an array, where index is reachable sum, and value - bill number, by which this sum is reached.

This approach is used in the [Emercoin](http://emercoin.com/) transaction optimizer.
See source code at:

https://github.com/Emercoin/emercoin/blob/master/src/wallet.cpp#L1112

Memory is O(Sum); Time is O(Sum * NumBills);
See short article about it:

http://cointelegraph.com/news/emercoin-implements-solution-to-reduce-blocksize-inflation

Answer (score 0):

See my solution in this question [Coin Change Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37983451/dynamic-programming-pr0blem-on-coins/37983523#37983523)

Also for such kind of problem, the hard part is always to determine if the coin / money system is canonical *i.e. Can use greedy algorithm*